# MVC3 HTML.Checkbox in "Details" view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I find very little out anywhere about how to utilize HTML helpers to render a "Details" view. First case is I have some bit fields in SQL Server that are bools in my pocos. This all works fine for the Create and Edit views but if I want a check box to show in the details view with it's appropriate state set but readonly...I can't figure out how to do it. I've got this:

```
<div class="display-field">@Html.CheckBox("laptops", Model.laptops, new { @readonly = "true" }) </div>
```

While it renders correctly the check box isn't readonly.

Same thing with handling fields that are DropDowns on Create/Edit but what about best practices for the Details view? What's the best way to resolve the FK to the displayable name representing that value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you run this page what does the generated code/html look like ? can you add that ?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to render a readonly checkbox is this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.laptops, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Notice the usage of the strongly typed `CheckBoxFor` helper instead of `CheckBox` as you already have a strongly typed view. And obviously for this to work the `laptops` property on your model must be of type boolean as that's the only possible type that would make sense for a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

When you set READONLY it simply prevents the user from making any changes to the underlying data, but they can still check/uncheck the field.
Set the DISABLED property to prevent them from interacting with the control like so:

```
 @Html.CheckBox("check", item.CheckedOrNot, new { @disabled = true })
```

Good Luck, cheers!